# display file data in an android app?

Tags: android, file

I am trying to do an android project. In that, I have created a file named fie.txt. I want the data(integers) stored in that file. How can I to retrieve and display that using android studio?

Comment: what format does your data use? Where is your file.txt located? If you don't bother with trying to write some code, at least tell us your *exact* prerequisites

Comment: Whenever I need to speak a foreign language (English, Spanish, French, Italian) one of the most important things is that it **sounds** like the listeners language. What I say doesn't have to be perfect. The same for writing English: make it look like English by putting a space behind all punctuation, and never before punctuation. "So" is relatively seldom be used (in written or spoken text), try to leave it out. Instead of statement "I don't know how to... ." use a question: "How can I ... ?"

Answer (score 0):

You could read it line by line like this:

```
FileInputStream fis;
final StringBuffer storedString = new StringBuffer();

try {
    fis = openFileInput("out.txt");
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
    String strLine = null;

    if ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
        storedString.append(strLine);
    }

    dataIO.close();
    fis.close();
}
catch  (Exception e) {  
}
```

or when you place your file in a`raw` folder in your `res` folder, you could open it and read it like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.you_file_name);

InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
String line;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
String wholeTextFromFile = text.toString();
```